# Print out hex of invisible characters in Java

Tags: java, printing, character-encoding, hex

I want to print out some invisible characters in a file. If I open the file in Xcode, it shows '^@' as invisible characters, and in TextMate there are grey diamonds if I have the option "show invisibles" on.

I tried the following code but the Hex printed out is "00", which represents null I think. How can I print out the corresponding hex for the actual invisible characters in the file? Thanks in advance!

```
     File file = new File("withInvisibles.txt");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner (file);

     while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String words= sc.next();

                System.out.println(String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, words.getBytes())));
            }
            sc.close();
```

Comment: `NUL` is an invisible character. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is that I think the invisible characters in that file aren't 'Nul's ? Otherwise how come the text editors show  '^@'  and grey diamonds?

Comment: Plus I am studying a stego program that embeds invisible characters into text files, and there is no piece of code enbed "00" nul in that program..

Answer (score 0):

Use `(char)System.in.read()` instead of Scanner.